# How to develop Android Studio projects with different SDK paths

Tags: android-studio

I happened to have two different Android SDK paths for different projects. Every time I launched a project with a different SDK path, Android Studio asked which path to use, and made the path a system-level SDK path. Is it possible to make Android Studio to use the locally defined SDK path by default? This will make developing multiple Android Studio projects with different SDK paths at the same time possible.